# Maven dependency not found for org.bukkit:bukkit

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, dependencies, minecraft

The `groudID`, `artifactId` and `version` dependencies are not being found in Maven?

I followed [this](http://wiki.bukkit.org/Plugin_Tutorial) tutorial to set up a Minecraft plugin which uses Maven.

But I get the error

> org.bukkit:bukkit:1.7.2-RO3 not found

and the text font is red where everything else in the `pom` file is white.

Here is the code in the pom file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.chrismepham</groupId>
    <artifactId>TestPlugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>bukkit-repo</id>
            <url>https://hub.spigotmc.org/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.bukkit</groupId>
            <artifactId>bukkit</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.2-R0.3</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Why is the dependency not being found?
EDIT:

I changed the repository and dependency version as suggested but still have the error as shown in the picture:
[image: red text]

Comment: Simply cause the given version does not exist in the defined repository.

Comment: 1.8-R0.1-SNAPSHOT only exists in the given repository

Comment: I changed the version to `1.8-R0.1-SNAPSHOT` and all three are still red

Comment: The reason its still red is possibly because intelliJ hasn't re-imported the pom.xml, see my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason the text is red is because that dependency you've specified can't be found in either maven central, or the additional repository you've added.

Paste the repo link into a browser, and you'll find that the dependency is actually `1.8-R0.1-SNAPSHOT` not `1.7.2-RO3` as the tutorial mentioned (maybe the tutorial is out of date, or that dependency has since been removed for some reason)

Change the dep to

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.bukkit</groupId>
            <artifactId>bukkit</artifactId>
            <version>1.8-R0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

If you haven't already set auto-import on intelliJ, you'll get a popup in the top right hand corner asking if you want to re-import. IntelliJ then reads your pom.xml file, works out what dependencies you need and then downloads them.

You should see org.bukkit.bukkit under external dependencies in the left hand "projects" window, along with some other libraries it depends on, such as guava and commons lang.

Answer (score 2):

Posting as an answer for anyone who stumbles upon this as I could not find an answer that worked for me with 1.20.

While trying to get the correct Maven dependency for `org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin` I found [this page](https://www.spigotmc.org/wiki/spigot-maven/) on Spigot's site that pointed me to the correct dependency information that solved my issues.

**pom.xml**

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spigot-repo</id>
        <url>https://hub.spigotmc.org/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
           <groupId>org.spigotmc</groupId>
           <artifactId>spigot-api</artifactId>
           <version>1.20.1-R0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
           <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 1):

[Bukkit as a Maven dependency](http://wiki.bukkit.org/Bukkit_as_a_Maven_Dependency) suggests a different repository:

```
<repository>
  <id>bukkit-repo</id>
  <url>http://repo.bukkit.org/content/groups/public/</url>
</repository>
```

On inspection, it [includes 1.7.2-R0.3](https://repo.bukkit.org/content/groups/public/org/bukkit/bukkit/1.7.2-R0.3/).

(It also works over SSL, as `https://repo.bukkit.org/content/groups/public/`, which you should prefer.)

Comment: I changed the pom file as you suggested but it hasn't helped, I attached a screenshot, perhaps it will help identify the issue?

Answer (score 0):

The dependency doesn't exist in the repo. If you follow the [repository link](https://hub.spigotmc.org/nexus/content/groups/public/org/bukkit/bukkit/), you see that the only version inside is **1.8-R0.1-SNAPSHOT**. So you must change that version inside your pom.